# Ionic 4 *ngFor with numeric values

Tags: ionic4

I have ion-slide that iterates n times (n can be 0 or up to 100, any integer).

The variable n is given in typescript as an element of a collection.

How can I make the * ngFor, iterate from 0 to n, numeric?

thanks!

Comment: have you try tweaking this one -> https://lishman.io/using-ngfor-to-repeat-n-times-in-angular

Comment: Hello lussac, thank you very much for answering, I clarify my question, I have been a little wrong.

I have several horizontal ion-slides (one below the other), each with X cards inside. X is variable for each slide.

In each element of the collection, comes a number (Z) of cards from the slide, so the question is:

How can I make the * ngFor of the cards iterate from 1 to the number Z indicated in the collection?